# iOS/Android does not show keyboard onload

Tags: javascript, html

how to show the keyboard without some kind of user interaction.

I need to show the keyboard on load the page.

Is this possible ?

I have tried to click button its show the keyboard on input field, but on load i can't able to show the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is just to hide a hidden textbox behind the `loader` and set the focus on that textbox using javascript `document.getElementById("hidden-text").focus()`. Because the keyboard will popup only when the focus is on any input box.

```js
document.getElementById("hidden-text").focus();
```

```css
#hidden-text {
  z-index: 0;
}

.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #F00;
  padding-top: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<input id="hidden-text" type="input" />
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)